# Usage of only external Monitor -> Screen Black with Mouse but mirror or extend is fine on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: multiple-monitors, 20.04

First of all i am new to Linux/Ubuntu. After a failed Upgrade to 20.04LTS from 18.04LTS i managed to kinda repair it. But there where a lot of questions about upgrade configurations which where altered somehow, i chose to keep them maybe this is the problem.

But one thing is still kinda broken, as soon as i close the lid with connected external screen only the external monitor was used. Now the external screen is black only with a mouse, can not open a terminal or at least i can not see it.

The same behavior is followed by any change to use only the external screen. (Display Settings or Fn+F7 "switching between only extend/mirror/InternalOnly/ExternalOnly")

I have a Thinkpad and using a external Screen per hdmi->dvi.

I have no clue how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

The [Oled-dimmer](https://github.com/fiji-flo/oled_dimmer) gnome plugin was causing the issue, before the ubuntu 20.04 upgrade it worked. But now it does not work with the external Monitor only setup.

After disabling the Extension, i can use my external monitor again.